# Save the current selection as HTML in Excel with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

In Excel, when saving a workbook to an HTML file, one has the choice to save the entire workbook or the current selection only.

How can one programmatically perform the latter using VBA?

Comment: See Ron de Bruin's `RangeToHtml` function [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm)